# Mdx STRTOMEMBER with member properties

Tags: mdx

I want to get the property value for the below dynamic  member.

**STRTOMEMBER("[User].[User].["+mid(username,instr(username,'\')+1)+"])**

member property is **.Properties("Power User ")**

I tried diffrent combination with Properties but no luck

tried below one but its not working

STRTOMEMBER("[User].[User].["+mid(username,instr(username,'\')+1)+"].Properties(""Power User" ")")

Please help me to get the correct mdx.

Thanks,

Javed

Answer (score 0):

I would think that

```
StrToMember("[User].[User].["+mid(username,instr(username,'\')+1)+"]")
.Properties("Power User ")
```

should work. The `StrToMember` function delivers an object of type member, on which you then can apply the `Properties` function.